# Why are git push / pull not working. I get no errors and the operation doesn't finish

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have tried to setup git with Github.

I generated the SSH key, inserted it in the Account and all that stuff. I followed every step thoroughly, in my view.

My OS is Linux Debian 8.

I want to do these standard operations for my new repo:

```
git init
git add README.md 
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:beselig/destroytheworld.git
```

until here everything works

```
git push -u origin master'
```

This results in the cmd-line starting the operation for pushing the commit, but I get neither an error message nor any feedback whatsoever about whether something is being done or not. Github shows no change, my local repo shows no change.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like my server setup is broken in some way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not writing the last command correctly, this should work:

```
git init
git add README.md 
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:beselig/destroytheworld.git
git push -u origin master # remove the ' after master
```

Comment: hey, sorry for the ultra late response. Yes the single quote was truly just stupid, however it slipped into my code and it wouldn't have worked without it. It turned out that the gitlab-host (we have a private hosting service) doesn't allow the remote origin to be a ssh-link. With https it worked. Thank you anyway!